# Android parse-SDK-android and facebook SDK incompatibility

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform

Latest versions of android parse SDK (1.24.x) include bolts-tasks instead of referencing it. In an app which also use Facebook SDK this leads to duplicate classes :

java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class bolts.AggregateException found in modules bolts-tasks-1.24.1.jar (com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:bolts-tasks:1.24.1) and bolts-tasks-1.4.0.jar (com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0)
  Duplicate class bolts.AndroidExecutors found in modules bolts-tasks-1.24.1.jar (com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:bolts-tasks:1.24.1) and bolts-tasks-1.4.0.jar (com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0)
  Duplicate class bolts.AndroidExecutors$1 found in modules bolts-tasks-1.24.1.jar (com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:bolts-tasks:1.24.1) and bolts-tasks-1.4.0.jar (com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0)
  Duplicate class bolts.AndroidExecutors$UIThreadExecutor found in modules bolts-tasks-1.24.1.jar (com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:bolts-tasks:1.24.1) and bolts-tasks-1.4.0.jar (com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0)
  Duplicate class bolts.BoltsExecutors found in modules bolts-tasks-1.24.1.jar (com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:bolts-tasks:1.24.1) and bolts-tasks-1.4.0.jar (com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0)
  Duplicate class bolts.BoltsExecutors$1 found in modules bolts-tasks-1.24.1.jar (com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:bolts-tasks:1.24.1) and bolts-tasks-1.4.0.jar (com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0)
...

Is there a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
implementation ("com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:parse:1.24.1"){
        exclude module:'bolts-tasks'
    }
```

If it doesn't work then try this

```
implementation ("com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:parse:1.24.1"){
        exclude group:'com.github.parse-community' ,module:'bolts-tasks'
    }
```

Comment: 'exclude' is used to suppress dependency but bolts-tasks is not a dependency of parse, Java sources are included in parse sources, so 'exclude' has no effect

Comment: But it works if I use exclude for Facebook SDK, now I need to test Facebook login in my app...

Answer (score 0):

if you are using  **com.facebook.fresco:fresco** then following solution is working

```
implementation ('com.facebook.fresco:fresco:2.1.0'){
        exclude module:'bolts-tasks'
    }
implementation "com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:parse:1.24.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

try this works for me

```
implementation "com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:parse:1.24.1"
implementation ('com.github.parse-community:ParseFacebookUtils-Android:1.14.0'){
        exclude module: 'bolts-android'
    }
```